# Tensorflow - conv3d.transpose - index out of range

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I am trying to create a 3D VAE Generative Adversarial Net. I am having issues with my first layer which is:

```
g1 = tf.nn.conv3d_transpose(z, filter = [4,4,4,512,200], strides= [1,1,1,1,1],
                              output_shape = (1,4,4,4,512), padding = "SAME")
```

where z is a (1,200) tensor which is the output of the encoder, which runs well. When I try running the session just to make sure things are flowing with the Generator, I  get the following error:

```
File "/home/michantia/anaconda2/envs/tf-gpu/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/nn_ops.py", line 1401, in conv3d_transpose
if not value.get_shape()[axis].is_compatible_with(filter.get_shape()[4]):

File "/home/michantia/anaconda2/envs/tf-gpu/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_shape.py", line 521, in __getitem__
return self._dims[key]

IndexError: list index out of range
```

The goal is to use several layers to generate a 32x32x32 voxel representation.

I am not quite sure what I am doing wrong here. Any feedback is highly appreciated.

Thanks,

M

Answer (score 1):

To avoid this error, you must declare the input, the filter and the output like  placeholders before use them.

Moreover, to use the [tf.nn.conv3d_transpose](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/conv3d_transpose), you have to have a 5D tensor in input. Following that, you have to declare z like a 5D placeholder:

```
z = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(1,200,1,1,200))

filter = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(4,4,4,512,200))

out = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=(5,))
```

Note that the output must be an `int32` and not a `float32`.

After that, you can declare your transposed convolution:

```
g1 = tf.nn.conv3d_transpose(z, filter, out, [1,1,1,1,1],padding = "SAME")
```